# InfluxDB localmachine not able to recognize other machines having public IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, cluster-computing, influxdb, amazon-ec2

I want to launch a cluster with one machine inside my home network and other having public IP.

I configured the file `/etc/default/influxdb/` by adding the following line:

```
INFLUXD_OPTS="-join <Public-IP>:8091"
```

I followed [official documentation](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v0.10/clustering/cluster_setup/) of influxdb cluster settings.

I added rules for port 8086,8091 to the security groups. I am able to do telnet to that port.

```
show servers
name: data_nodes
----------------
id  http_addr       tcp_addr

1   localhost:8086  localhost:8088


name: meta_nodes
----------------
id  http_addr       tcp_addr

1   localhost:8091  localhost:8088
```

How to launch a cluster with one machine in my home network and other machine in aws cloud having public IP?

Answer (score 0):

The AWS machines cannot reach your `localhost`. You must use domain names that are fully resolvable by every member of the cluster. Even once that's working, a cluster connected over the public internet is likely to fail due to latency issues.

Comment: ok,actually I need to synchronize the two cluster machines for testing purposes.